# Не корректно работает сортировка ORDER BY

Tags: php, sql, кодировка

Доброго времени! ПРоблема такая - не корректно сортируется выборка вот запрос:

```
$tmpl = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM leners WHERE idg='$ida' ORDER BY name ASC");
```

в поле name записаны ФИО кирилица, кодировка поля тоже utf8 general ci, кодировка документа тоже utf8 - НО в PMA при просмотре таблицы все имена выглядат приерно так

```
 ÐÐ±Ð°Ð¹Ò±Ð»Ñ‹ Ð‘Ð°ÑƒÑ‹Ñ€Ð¶Ð°Ð½
```

это связанно с тем что при соединении с БД не выставили кодировку в свое время, по этому данные записываются нормально, при выводе на сайте тоже имеют нормальный вид, но в БД хранятся в виде кракозябр, мне кажется сортировка не работает из-за этого т.к. сортируются они в виде кракозябр. Есть ли какое то решение что бы не менять кодировки (боюсь потерять уже записанные в БД данные) но что бы сортировка проходила нормально, может указать как то кодировку уже с самом запросе sql или при mysql_fetch_array как то задавать сортировку по имени?

Comment: А в настройках PMA какая кодировка указана?

Comment: чтобы не бояться потерять данные делайте бэкап БД. Чтобы указать кодировку в запросе используйте `order by name asc collate utf8_general_ci`, но это частное решение, и лучше решить проблему глобально.

Answer (score -2):

В заголовке ответа нужно utf-8 поставить.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: @Павел Кузнецов , извините это получается а заголовке запроса как то надо прописать??